# Laravel retrieve data from database and format

Tags: database, laravel, get, format

What is a good way of retrieving data from the database und formating them afterwards:

Current I have this show method in my controller:

```
public function showProduct($productID = 0)
{
    $product   = Product::find($productID);
    $companies = Companies::where('active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort', 'Asc')->get();

    return view('product.show', ['product' => $product, 'companies' => $companies]);
}
```

and in my show.blade.php I retrieve the data like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    {{ $product }}
@endsection
```

but it just shows me the data in an array, how can I make this more beautiful like creating a table and sorting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{$product->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{$product->text}}</p>
@endsection
```